# Creating MMO using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I will be using javacript and HTML to create a game in canvas in my planning stage however I started to wonder how I was gonna handle multiple users editing and playing on the same "canvas" per say

So to describe my issue I wanna tell you a little about the game

When I was 7(now 18) I played this amazing game called "Pocket Empires" it brought `Teamwork` to a whole new playing field it had everything you see in the modern day "Clash of Clans" but while in battle if you were struggling your alliance members could jump in the battle and save you

It was truly a remarkable game I encourage everyone to look it up

This game however was android only and fell through the cracks in 2013 and I have looked for a game clone since but have found nothing truly like it since so now I am going to create it myself

The main thing about the game I am concerned with is displaying the same thing across all screens for example

Player 1 places a building
Player 2 should see that on his screen

or

Player 1 is attacking some goblins
Player 2(if in the same alliance) should see player 1 attacking and should be able to join in

I have done a lot of research over the years I have a web development certificate in both HTML and CSS(as if that actually mattered) Afterwards I spent another 2 years learning Javacript and PHP

Now I know php will not be of use without ajax which I want to avoid at all cost so thats all the information I believe I can provide now I leave it to y'all to lead me in the right direction

Comment: Why do you want to avoid ajax at all cost ?

Comment: I think this is way too broad a request to answer. You're essentially asking "How do I get started on making an MMO?". There's a lot of resources available on the net by just performing a Google search. I'd probably advise starting much much smaller and not multiplayer centered (to familiarse yourself with actually making a game first).

Comment: Not familiar with it

Comment: Ive made plenty of games in the past and am very familiar with how to do so the issue is making the games mmo not sure what to use to accomplish it @Dandy

Comment: Don't know the game (and I'm not a game programmer), but verrrrry generally ... Make a spritesheet containing all game pieces, position the game pieces using a JSON "game-status" object, use websockets to send the game-status objects to everyone and to receive moves from players.

Comment: MMO games run on servers, the client is just a terminal used to display information to the user and relay IO back to the server. As one answer stated websockets are the way to manage data movement from client to server, they are basicly an open two way channel that you can push data onto. All the hard work will be at the server side as that is where the game is being played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web sockets to :

- send the action of the user to the server
- get the actions of others player and to show what needs to